# Bad Deployment with eclipse on server JBoss

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

i wrote an enterprise java application EAR that include a servlet with a jsp page where the user put in a form the request and with the servlet's doPost method i manage there request forwording the action to do to two EJB. So i use the ejb from the Servlet making the lookup with @EJB myServelt nameSevlet and call the method of the servlet. 
My problem is that if i add to the EJBs or to Servlet the external jars library and write a function that use these libraries  whene i start the server from eclipse that automatically makes the deployment i reach these errors:

```
15:09:08,167 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."myEnterprisePrj.ear"."myWebPrj.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."myEnterprisePrj.ear"."myWebPrj.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "myWebPrj.war" of deployment "myEnterprisePrj.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class my.servlet.myServlet with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.myEnterprisePrj.ear.myWebPrj.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom2/JDOMException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom2.JDOMException from [Module "deployment.myEnterprisePrj.ear.myWebPrj.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more

15:09:08,172 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named PlaceSessionBean in deployment unit subdeployment "PlaceEJB.jar" of deployment "myEnterprisePrj.ear" are as follows:

    java:global/myEnterprisePrj/PlaceEJB/PlaceSessionBean!place.bean.PlaceSessionBean
    java:app/PlaceEJB/PlaceSessionBean!place.bean.PlaceSessionBean
    java:module/PlaceSessionBean!place.bean.PlaceSessionBean
    java:global/myEnterprisePrj/PlaceEJB/PlaceSessionBean
    java:app/PlaceEJB/PlaceSessionBean
    java:module/PlaceSessionBean


15:09:08,196 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 3491ms - Started 170 of 261 services (8 services failed or missing dependencies, 82 services are passive or on-demand)
15:09:08,406 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "myEnterprisePrj.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"myEnterprisePrj.ear\".\"myWebPrj.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"myEnterprisePrj.ear\".\"myWebPrj.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"myWebPrj.war\" of deployment \"myEnterprisePrj.ear\""},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean]"]}
15:09:08,431 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment PlaceEJB.jar in 10ms
15:09:08,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment myWebPrj.war in 11ms
15:09:08,432 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment GeocorderEJB.jar in 11ms
15:09:08,445 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment myEnterprisePrj.ear in 25ms
15:09:08,448 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean.Validator] 
      service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean.Validator] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."myEnterprisePrj.ear"."myWebPrj.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."myEnterprisePrj.ear"."myWebPrj.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "myWebPrj.war" of deployment "myEnterprisePrj.ear"

15:09:08,457 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"myEnterprisePrj.ear\".\"myWebPrj.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"myEnterprisePrj.ear\".\"myWebPrj.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"myWebPrj.war\" of deployment \"myEnterprisePrj.ear\""},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.GeocorderEJB.GeocorderSessionBean]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.myEnterprisePrj.PlaceEJB.PlaceSessionBean]"]}}}
```

I use jdom2 jarexternal library. But if i load the jar from buildPath of project and i don't write any code that call the methods of the library the deployments has success.
Also i see in the directory JbossFinal7.1/standalone/deployments/myEnterpriseProject.ear that there is no lib folder and no jar file, so i don't know where is the referiment to the library.
I can't find the solution.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: HOW are you deploying the application to the server? Through the JBoss Tools plugin? If not, that is highly recommended to do. In your project, be sure that the deployment assembly is properly setup. You can find that through the project properties.

Comment: Thranks very much i resolve setting up the file that must be deploy in deployments assemby ;)